# Topology generated by a basis or subbasis is the intersection of all topologies containing it

Tags: general-topology

I am self studying Munkres' *Topology* and was struck on this exercise question of section 13. I don't have any help from teacher or friends.  So, I am asking for any explanation here.

The question is

> Show that if $A$ is a basis for a topology on $X$, then the topology generated by $A$ equals the intersection of all topologies on $X$ that contain $A$.
>   Prove the same if $A$ is a subbasis.

The intuition is clear to me but I don't know how to write a proper proof. 
Can you please tell me for both parts.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Ok sir.  I will keep it in mind in future

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $\mathcal{B}$ is a base for a topology $\mathcal{T}$.

We want to show $$\mathcal{T} = \bigcap \{ \mathcal{T}': \mathcal{T}' \text{ is a topology on } X; \mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathcal{T}'\}$$

So let $O$ be in $\mathcal{T}$, and we want to show it is in the intersection, so let $\mathcal{T}'$ be any topology that contains $\mathcal{B}$ as a subset. Then $O$ in $\mathcal{T}$ means that $O = \bigcup \mathcal{B'}$ where $\mathcal{B}' \subseteq \mathcal{B}$, because the topology generated by a base is the set of unions of subfamilies of that base (!). But so $$\mathcal{B}' \subseteq \mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathcal{T}'$$ and as $\mathcal{T}'$ is closed under unions (being a topology), $O \in \mathcal{T}'$.

As $\mathcal{T}'$ was an arbitary topology that makes up the intersection we have that $O$ is in the right hand intersection of topologies. This shows one inclusion.

One minor modification is needed for the subbase case: if $\mathcal{S}$ is a subbase for that same topology $\mathcal{T}$, then we can define a base $\mathcal{B}$ from it by taking all intersections of finite subfamilies of $\mathcal{S}$ and $\mathcal{T}$ is then also the topology generated by $\mathcal{B}$, and any topology $\mathcal{T}'$ that contains $\mathcal{S}$ will also contain $\mathcal{B}$, as all topologies are closed under finite intersections, so the subbase case reduces to the base case.

The other, reverse inclusion is trivial, in both cases. $\mathcal{T}$ (the set of unions of base subfamilies) is itself one of the topologies that contains $\mathcal{B}$ (as each member $B \in \mathcal{B}$ is trivially the union of $\{B\} \subseteq \mathcal{B}$ and by previous results we know the set of unions is a topology) and so trivially, if $O$ is in the intersection it is in $\mathcal{T}$ in particular.

So we have equality of topologies. In all pedantic detail...

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation.

Comment: I am not good in proof writing in topology because our instructor on this course is very bad. So, I am forced to search it on Internet as no proofs are discussed in class. Your answer made me understand it. Thank you very much for replying.

Comment: @AD not that I’m begging, but upvotes for helpful answers is the thing to do on this site...

Comment: My reputation is less than 15. So,  my votes are not counted.

Comment: Also, If I do a mistake or you have any advice for me then please tell me as I am new on these site and I have no experience of discussion groups.

Comment: I guess I can green tick only one answer.  But all other answers were also helpful for me.  Thanks to all the writers who helped me.  Also my reputation is less than 15 so my upvotes are not recorded.

Answer (score 2):

In lemma 13.1 in Munkres it is proved that - if $\mathcal A$ is a basis for a topology $\tau$ on $X$ - this topology is the collection of all unions of elements of $\mathcal A$.

Now let it be that $\rho$ is a topology on $X$ with $\mathcal A\subseteq\rho$.

Then - because $\rho$ is closed under arbitrary unions - it is immediate that also $\tau\subseteq\rho$.

So if $\mathcal T:=\{\rho\mid \rho\text{ is a topology on }X\text{ with }\mathcal A\subseteq\rho\}$ then $\tau\subseteq\bigcap\mathcal T$.

Next to that we have $\tau\in\mathcal T$ so that also $\bigcap\mathcal T\subseteq\tau$.

This together proves that $$\tau=\bigcap \mathcal T$$

---

For a subbase $\mathcal S$ you can reason likewise. Use the fact that by definition the topology generated by $\mathcal S$ is the collection of all unions of finite intersections of elements of $\mathcal S$.

Comment: Just a note on typesetting: you might want to use $\bigcap\mathcal T$ instead of $\cap\mathcal T$ for intersection over systems of sets.

Comment: @Christoph Thanks for the suggestion, but I see $\cap$ as an operator on non-empty sets in the sense that $x\in\cap a\iff\forall y\in a[x\in y]$. The $\bigcap$ I use when indices are involved. Actually $\cap T=\bigcap_{\tau\in\mathcal T}\tau$ and $\cap\{A_i\mid i\in I\}=\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i$ according to my standards.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I understood it till Line no 11. After that line  - next to that we have

Comment: Is not clear.  Can you please explain in more detail

Comment: Are you saying that $\tau\in\mathcal T\implies\cap\mathcal T\subseteq\tau$ is not clear for you?

Comment: If $x\in\cap\mathcal T$ then $x\in\rho$ for every topology $\rho$ on $X$ that satisfies $\mathcal A\subseteq\rho$. Topology $\tau$ is such a topology, so $x\in\tau$. This proves that $\cap\mathcal T\subseteq\tau$.

Comment: Yer sir.  I could not write it in terms of tau because I use a simple cell phone.  Can you please explain it.

Comment: I have explained it in my former comment. There I showed that $x\in\cap\mathcal T$ implies that $x\in\tau$.

Comment: Ok yes, thank you very much for explanation.

Comment: You are very welcome

Answer (score 1):

Let $\tau$ be the topology generated by $A$.  Clearly $\tau$ contains $A$.  Thus one direction is obvious.

But the other is also easy, because by definition $\tau$ is the coarsest topology containing $A$.  This means $\tau\subset\rho$ for every topology $\rho$ containing $A$.

This reasoning works if $A$ is a basis or sub-basis.