# Proving that the topology generated by a basis is the intersection over containing topologies.

Tags: general-topology

I am thinking about the problem:

> Let $A$ be a basis for a topology on $X$, and let $\mathfrak T = \{\mathcal T: T \text{ is a topology on $X$ such that } A\subseteq \mathcal T \}$.  Then the topology generated by $A$ is $\bigcap_{\mathcal T\in\mathfrak T}\mathcal T$.

I have seen a few solutions of this problem, such as here: [Topology generated by a basis or subbasis is the intersection of all topologies containing it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2906153/topology-generated-by-a-basis-or-subbasis-is-the-intersection-of-all-topologies)

However, I think there is a subtle logical error in all of the solutions I've found, which is that they all assume that there is some topology which is the topology generated by $A$.  This problem is in Munkres, section 13, and by the time that the problem is posed, he has not proved that there exists a topology generated by $A$ for each basis $A$.  It seems like there should be, but as of the point where this problem is posed, when we know that $A$ is "a basis for a topology" that's just a name for a bunch of properties on $A$, but there is no obvious reason to think that any topology has the properties of "the topology generated by $A$".

Since each proof that I have found so far for this problem, assumes the existence of a topology generated by $A$, I feel the need to find a proof without this assumption.

This proof seems to recognize the problem: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Existence_and_Uniqueness_of_Generated_Topology

But that proof seems not to use the same definition of "the topology generated by a basis" as Munkres does, and I don't see a straight-forward adaptation of the proof there.

---

With the assumptions as described above, we want to show that $\mathcal I = \bigcap_{\mathcal T\in\mathfrak T}\mathcal T$ satisfies the conditions for being the topology generated by $A$.  That means that we need to choose an arbitrary $U\in \mathcal I$ and $x\in U$, and then demonstrate the existence of some $B\in A$ such that $x\in B$ and $B\subseteq U$.

Of course we know that there is some $B\in A$ such that $x\in B$ since $A$ is a basis.  Moreover, because $A\subseteq \mathcal T$ for each $\mathcal T\in\mathfrak T$, then $B\in \mathcal T$.  Therefore $B\in \mathcal I$.

We only need to show that there is some $B'\in A$ such that $x\in B'$ and $B'\subseteq U$.  I don't see how we could justify taking $B=B'$ above since I don't see a justification for $B\subseteq U$.  But also, I'm not sure of how to find another $B'\subseteq U$.  It would be nice if we could somehow argue that $B\cap U\in A$ but I don't see a justification for that.

---

[How Munkres defines the topology generated by a basis:]

If $\mathcal B$ satisfies [the conditions for being a basis], then we define the **topology $\mathcal T$ generated by $\mathcal B$** as follows: A subset $U$ of $X$ is said to be open in $X$ (that is, to be an element of $\mathcal T$) if for each $x\in U$, there is a basis element $B\in\mathcal B$ such that $x\in B$ and $B\subset U$.  Note that each basis element is itself an element of $\mathcal T$.

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku Added to the end of the post.

Comment: Ok I added an answer.

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku I may be misunderstanding, but it seems that you assume $\mathcal T_{\mathcal B}$ exists.

Comment: Does munkres *not* prove that? You do realise that my defintion is just a slight reformualtion of munkres?

Comment: No, Munkres does not prove the existence of the topology generated by a basis.

Comment: Ok added a proof.

Comment: Concerning your addendum, that is not how Munkres defines the topology generated by a basis. You must also include the condition that $A \subseteq \mathcal T$, as otherwise it doesn't determine a unique topology. In particular, the trivial topology always meets the condition, regardless of $A$.

Comment: Interesting, although I'm not sure where this is in Munkres' definition.  I'll update the post with a direct quotation.

Comment: Does my answer answer your question?

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku I'm afraid not -- as far as I can tell it always assumed the existence that I'm asking about proving.  But in fact, I think I figured it out, and my question is just kind of silly.  For whatever reason, when reading this section, I didn't realize that we were merely defining a subset of the powerset  of the space.  A subset of a set, subject to any well-defined condition, always exists by the axioms of set theory.  So anyway, I think the question came from a pretty basic misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

Per Munkres given a basis $\mathcal{B}$, the topology generated by $\mathcal{B}$ is the family of sets $\mathcal{T}_\mathcal{B}$ such that  $U\in \mathcal{T}_\mathcal{B}\iff U \text{ is the union of elements in } \mathcal{B}$, It can be checked that family is a topology. It is clear that $\mathcal{I}\subseteq\mathcal{T}_\mathcal{B}$, further the reverse direction holds since $\mathcal{B}\subseteq \mathcal{I}$, and topologies are closed under unions.

**Edit:** Proving $\mathcal{T}_\mathcal{B}$ is a topology is not hard, the only non trivial part is closure under finite intersections but that follows from the fact that if $B_{1}, B_{2} \in \mathcal{B}$ then for every point $x\in B_{1} \cap B_{2}$ there exists a $B_{3}$ such that $x\in B_{3}$ and $B_{3}\subseteq B_{1}\cap B_{2}$.