# Topology generated by a set and definition of a sub-basis

Tags: general-topology

The usual definition of a basis $\mathcal{B}$ of a topology states that any set $U$ in the topology is the union of sets from a subcollection of $\mathcal{B}$. This topology is then often called the topology generated by $\mathcal{B}$. It can be shown that this topology is the intersection of all topologies that contain $\mathcal{B}$. (see here [Topology generated by a basis or subbasis is the intersection of all topologies containing it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2906153/topology-generated-by-a-basis-or-subbasis-is-the-intersection-of-all-topologies?noredirect=1&lq=1) ). This means it is the smallest topology that contains $\mathcal{B}$.

Now if I am looking at wikipedia it says "In general, if $X$ is a set and $\mathcal{B}$ is an arbitrary collection of subsets of $X$, there is a (unique) smallest topology $\tau$ containing $\mathcal{B}$. (This topology is the intersection of all topologies on $X$ containing $\mathcal{B}$.) The topology $\tau$ is called the topology generated by $\mathcal{B}$, and $\mathcal{B}$ is called a sub-base for $\tau$ ."
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)

In fact on the wikipedia page for sub-basis they define the sub-basis such that:
"The subcollection $\mathcal{B}$ generates the topology $\tau$ . This means that $\tau$ is the smallest topology containing $\mathcal{B}$: any topology
$\tau*$ on $X$ containing $\mathcal{B}$ must also contain $\tau$ ."

So to me it sounds like the definition of a sub-basis is actually exactly what it means if a basis generates a topology (see top of this question). My question therefore is, what is the difference here, since generally basis and subbasis are different objects? Similarly, when do we really say that a topology is generated by some collection $\mathcal{B}$? If it is a basis or if it is a sub-basis?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144850/discussion-on-question-by-guest1-topology-generated-by-a-set-and-definition-of-a); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3):

TFAE:

- $\mathcal B$ is a subbase of the topology $\tau$ (on $X$)
- $\tau$ is the smallest topology on $X$ containing $\mathcal B$
- $\tau$ is the intersection of all topologies on $X$ containing $\mathcal B$
- $U\in\tau$ iff $U$ is a union of finite intersections (which may be $\bigcap\varnothing:=X$) of elements of $\mathcal B.$

A base is a subbase $\mathcal B$ such that for every $U,V\in\mathcal B,$ $U\cap V$ is a union of elements of $\mathcal B,$ or equivalently: such that any finite intersection of elements of $\mathcal B$ is a union of elements of $\mathcal B.$ (Proof: every base $\mathcal B$ satisfies this, since (by definition of a base) the unions of elements of $\mathcal B$ are the open sets of a topology, and if $U,V$ are open then so is $U\cap V.$ Conversely, every subbase satisfying this is a base, since we may then drop "of finite intersections" in the fourth point above).

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144849/discussion-on-answer-by-anne-bauval-topology-generated-by-a-set-and-definition-o); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.