# Relation between basis and subbasis in topology

Tags: general-topology

I have two questions about the relation of bases and subbases in topology:

1.) Every basis is also a subbasis (for the same topology), but how can I show that? It means that any finite intersection of base elements are again in the basis. How can I show that?

2.) When constructing a basis from a subbasis via finite intersections, then we usually use the nullary convention to get the full set X as well (some other authors, like Munkrey, specifically already include in their Def of a subbasis that the elements shall cover X). Either way, the questions is why do we require that we get the full set X by means of finite intersections? It essentially means that the basis that we generate from the subbasis also includes X, but why is this necessary? A basis usually does not need to contain X it only has to provide a cover of X via some arbitrary union of elements from the basis.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4664239 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4664194 ?

Comment: A basis in general need not contain $X$.  It's fine to have $X$ in the basis, but it's equally fine if the basis is just a cover of $X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Question 1: The intersection of finitely many basis elements need not be a basis element. For example, in any metric space, the open balls form a basis, and the intersection of two open balls need not be a  ball --- for example in the Euclidean plane. Nevertheless, any basis $B$ is also a subbasis, because the intersections of finitely many sets from $B$ form a (possibly different) basis for the same topology.

For Question 2: Different authors have different conventions about subbases. In my opinion, the simplest version says that **any** collection $S$ of subsets of a set $X$ is a subbasis for a topology on $X$. That topology can be described either as the smallest topology that includes $S$ or as the family of all unions of finite intersections of elements of $S$. Here "finite intersections" includes the intersection of no sets from $S$, namely $X$, and "all unions" includes the union of no sets, namely $\varnothing$.

Other conventions result if the author doesn't want to consider intersections or unions of no sets (or doesn't expect readers to know about these vacuous cases). Then  $X$ and $\varnothing$ get added separately, rather than being included among the finite intersections and arbitrary unions.

Comment: Great thanks for your answer! So to reiterate the answer to Q1: A basis is a subbasis but as a subbasis it might generate a different basis. However, both theses bases generate the same topology. Is that correct?

Comment: Re Q2: So I want to know why it is necessary to already include a mechanism to obtain X when going from a subbasis to a basis. I.e., if I have the nullary convention and by Def of a subbasis I get a basis by finite intersections. Then this basis already contains X because of the finite intersections. But why is it needed to already have X contained in that basis (we would only need X to be in the topology so one step later). I.e., it would actually be sufficient that the basis does not contain X but covers X. So why do we use that convention and thereby enforce the inclusion of X in the basis?

Comment: @guest1 Your first comment is correct. For the second, I see no great need to include $X$ in the basis as long as it's a union of sets in the basis, but, as long as we're producing the basis by taking finite intersections of sets from the sub basis, why should we make an exception and omit the intersection of no sets? Especially since we'd have to put that intersection back into the basis if the rest of the basis didn't cover $X$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and good point!